# Mysql Date manipulation and divisible by

Tags: mysql

I have a cron that runs some php with some mysql just after midnight everyday. I want to take all registered users (to my website) and send them a reminder and copy of the newsletter. However I want to do this every 30 days from their registration.

I have thought as far as this:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DATE(DT_stamp) = DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY
```

But this will only work for 30 days after they have registered, not 60 and 90.

Effectively I want:

Where days since registration is divisible by 30

That way every 30 days that user will get picked up in the sql.

Can someone help me formulate this WHERE clause, I am struggling with mysql where day(date1-date2) divisible 30

Answer (score 5):

The [DATEDIFF](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_datediff) function returns the difference between two dates in days, ignoring the time:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE DATEDIFF(DT_stamp, NOW()) % 30 = 0
```

Answer (score 3):

or the other way round...

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(NOW(),registration_date),30) = 0;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use SQL modulo function [`MOD()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mathematical-functions.html#function_mod):

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE MOD( DATE(DT_stamp) - DATE(NOW()), 30) = 0
```

In mysql, you can also use the `%` operator, which does the same thing:

```
SELECT * FROM users
WHERE (DATE(DT_stamp) - DATE(NOW()) % 30 = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Just an addition (not that nine years had passed :)

If you want to skip today's date you should add

```
AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), DT_stamp) != 0;
```

making it

```
SELECT * FROM users WHERE MOD(DATEDIFF(NOW(), DT_stamp), 30) = 0 AND DATEDIFF(NOW(), DT_stamp) != 0;
```